# Capturing data for mapping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap

In my project I need the paths in a campus but these paths are non-existent so I'm going to walk around and map (I don't know if it's the correct term) the points to build the corresponding paths.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hand digitizing the paths in ArcMap 10 may be easier than walking around every path on campus with a GPS.  A really quick and easy way to accomplish your task is as follows:

1. Open ArcMap 10
2. Right click on a folder within the Catalog and select New > Shapefile
3. Click your new shapefile and select feature type "polyline"
4. Add a basemap (File > add data > add basemap > bing maps aerial)
5. Open editor (Customize > toolbars > editor)
6. Start editing and select your new shapefile in the create features
   window that pops up.
7. At the bottom of the create features pane select "line"
8. Begin selecting the vertices of your paths
9. When you are done select "save edits

That's it, you have your trails as a .shp file.  Best of luck!

[image]

Comment: This is amazing .. but it works under windows and I'm using linux.. but think I'm going to steal someone's computer for a while.. tnks

Comment: You can do the same in QGIS which will run on Linux.

Comment: Obviously doing it directly in a GIS is ideal but if that's an issue, just digitize the route in Google itself and save it as a KML.  You can then import it into almost any GIS on any operating system or just use the KML as is if you don't need any further editing.

Answer (score 5):

I presume you intend to use a GPS (possibly on your iPhone) for this.  Have a look at the excellent Open Street Map (OSM) project.  There is a guide on how to do exactly this here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners_Guide_1.1.

This should get you started.

Comment: +1 for OpenStreetMap. Great project, deserves recognition.