# Adding polygons to existing attribute table where data is stored as points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing

I have a shapefile of golf courses saved as points, I would like to digitise the boundaries and add the polygons to the existing attribute table.  I have opened editor and clicked on the point data shapefile but have no option to create a polygon.

Comment: You need to create a new shapefile as polygon - this can be done in ArcCatalogue or using the toolbox Create Feature Class (Data Management)  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002p000000.

Answer (score 5):

Your task is slightly more complicated than you would expect.  You will need to create a separate polygon shapefile/featureclass.  I would approach the problem as follows:

1. Add a new shapefile or feature class to your project (right click on
   folder/feature dataset > new Shapefile/Feature Class... > feature type "Polygon").  Make sure to define your coordinate system if you are working with a shapefile.  If you are familiar working with file geodatabases, I would recommend using it to sync the coordinate systems and simplify the area calculations of your polygons.
2. Open the editor and digitize your polygon boundaries.  Save edits.
3. Use [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) (ArcToolbox > Analysis Tools >
   Overlay) to join the attributes from your golf course point shapefile/featureclass to the attributes of your newly digitized golf course polygon
   shapefile/featureclass.

If you need additional help digitizing polygons, see this GIS SE [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28380/8104).